# How to process all subclass' members in superclass' constructor?

Tags: java, inheritance, reflection, subclassing

I want to write a class, say JComponentEx, which will enumerate all subclass members and add it to an object.

This way I will be able to write

```
class MyComponent extends JComponentEx {

    private JLabel mylabel = new JLabel();

    private JTextField mytext = new JTextField();

}
```

and this will cause automatic call to

```
this.add(mylabel);
this.add(mytext);
```

I understand some problems it will cause in the case of Swing. My question is how to implement the idea in principle.

**UPDATE**

In short words, I want to populate list with member definitions.

**UPDATE 2**

If I run addition inside constructor, I will not see members, since superclass constructor is executed before subclass instance initialized:

```
public class Try_Reflection_01 {

    private final static Logger log = LoggerFactory
            .getLogger(Try_Reflection_01.class);

    public static interface IAutoAdd {
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    public static class JComponentEx extends JComponent {

        public JComponentEx() {
            updateComponents();
        }

        protected void updateComponents() {
            log.info("In updateComponents()");
            for (Field f : getClass().getFields()) {

                try {
                    Object x = f.get(this);
                    log.info("Checking '{}' = {}", f.getName(), x);
                    if (x instanceof IAutoAdd) {
                        log.info("Adding");
                        add((JComponent)x);
                    }
                    else {
                        log.info("Not adding");
                    }

                } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                    log.error("Error getting member", e);
                } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                    log.error("Error getting member", e);
                }

            }
        }
    }

    public static class JMyComponent extends JComponentEx implements IAutoAdd {
        public JLabel label = new JLabel("my label");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JMyComponent component = new JMyComponent();
    }
}
```

outputs

```
[main] INFO test.java.Try_Reflection_01 - In updateComponents()
[main] INFO test.java.Try_Reflection_01 - Checking 'label' = null
[main] INFO test.java.Try_Reflection_01 - Not adding
[main] INFO test.java.Try_Reflection_01 - Checking 'WHEN_FOCUSED' = 0
[main] INFO test.java.Try_Reflection_01 - Not adding
[main] INFO test.java.Try_Reflection_01 - Checking 'WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT' = 1
[main] INFO test.java.Try_Reflection_01 - Not adding
[main] INFO test.java.Try_Reflection_01 - Checking 'WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW' = 2
[main] INFO test.java.Try_Reflection_01 - Not adding
[main] INFO test.java.Try_Reflection_01 - Checking 'UNDEFINED_CONDITION' = -1
[main] INFO test.java.Try_Reflection_01 - Not adding
[main] INFO test.java.Try_Reflection_01 - Checking 'TOOL_TIP_TEXT_KEY' = ToolTipText
[main] INFO test.java.Try_Reflection_01 - Not adding
[main] INFO test.java.Try_Reflection_01 - Checking 'TOP_ALIGNMENT' = 0.0
[main] INFO test.java.Try_Reflection_01 - Not adding
[main] INFO test.java.Try_Reflection_01 - Checking 'CENTER_ALIGNMENT' = 0.5
[main] INFO test.java.Try_Reflection_01 - Not adding
[main] INFO test.java.Try_Reflection_01 - Checking 'BOTTOM_ALIGNMENT' = 1.0
[main] INFO test.java.Try_Reflection_01 - Not adding
[main] INFO test.java.Try_Reflection_01 - Checking 'LEFT_ALIGNMENT' = 0.0
[main] INFO test.java.Try_Reflection_01 - Not adding
[main] INFO test.java.Try_Reflection_01 - Checking 'RIGHT_ALIGNMENT' = 1.0
[main] INFO test.java.Try_Reflection_01 - Not adding
[main] INFO test.java.Try_Reflection_01 - Checking 'WIDTH' = 1
[main] INFO test.java.Try_Reflection_01 - Not adding
[main] INFO test.java.Try_Reflection_01 - Checking 'HEIGHT' = 2
[main] INFO test.java.Try_Reflection_01 - Not adding
[main] INFO test.java.Try_Reflection_01 - Checking 'PROPERTIES' = 4
[main] INFO test.java.Try_Reflection_01 - Not adding
[main] INFO test.java.Try_Reflection_01 - Checking 'SOMEBITS' = 8
[main] INFO test.java.Try_Reflection_01 - Not adding
[main] INFO test.java.Try_Reflection_01 - Checking 'FRAMEBITS' = 16
[main] INFO test.java.Try_Reflection_01 - Not adding
[main] INFO test.java.Try_Reflection_01 - Checking 'ALLBITS' = 32
[main] INFO test.java.Try_Reflection_01 - Not adding
[main] INFO test.java.Try_Reflection_01 - Checking 'ERROR' = 64
[main] INFO test.java.Try_Reflection_01 - Not adding
[main] INFO test.java.Try_Reflection_01 - Checking 'ABORT' = 128
[main] INFO test.java.Try_Reflection_01 - Not adding
```

Answer (score 1):

Store them inside of a list instead of separate fields.

```
protected List<JComponent> components = new ArrayList<>();

// initializer
{
 components.add(new JLabel());
 components.add(new JTextField());
}
```

And when you want to use them:

```
for(JComponent comp : components){
 this.add(comp);
}
```

Alternative way to store them:

```
protected Map<String, JComponent> components = new HashMap<>();

{
 components.put("inputfield", new JTextField());
}
```

This will allow you to easily modify the components by using the key as an identifier.

If you really want to use reflection for this:

```
public class MyComponent {
    private JLabel mylabel = new JLabel();
    private JTextField mytext = new JTextField();

    private String someString;

    public List<JComponent> getComponents() throws IllegalArgumentException,
            IllegalAccessException {
        Field[] fields = this.getClass().getDeclaredFields();

        List<JComponent> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Field field : fields) {
            Object someField = field.get(this);
            if (someField instanceof JComponent) {
                list.add((JComponent) someField);
            }
        }

        return list;
    }
}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException{
        MyComponent comp = new MyComponent();
        System.out.println(comp.getComponents().size());
    }
}
```

Output:

> 2

Comment: They are already stored in the list, as in JComponent. Now I want to populate this list just with member declarations.

Comment: @SuzanCioc: what do you mean with 'member declarations'?

Comment: I want that line `private JLabel label = new JLabel();` automatically add `label` into underlying list, without any need to write `add(label)` explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use reflection - something like:

```
for(Field f: getClass().getFields()) {
  Object x = f.get(this);
  if(x instanceof JComponent) add(x);
}
```

Note that what I've given only works for public fields; accessing private fields is a little trickier - and it requires security permissions, so it won't work in an unsigned applet.

Comment: `getDeclaredFields()` works for private fields as well. `getFields()` is public only.

Comment: Yes, but I want to do this in superclass, so that subclass does not contain any code about that.

Comment: @RobinGreen if I put this code into superclass constructor, it will not see subclass members (they will be `null`). See my update.

Comment: That's true. Java does not offer a general way to run code after any constructor has been run, but AspectJ and Scala do offer that feature.